# On a constant associated to equilateral triangle and its generalization.

Tags: geometry

I guess many of you are familiar with the result described as follows:

**If ABC is an equilateral triangle, and P is any point on the incircle of ΔABC, then AP² + BP² + CP² is constant.** See link below.

http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/EquiIn3D.shtml

I was wondering whether this can be true for any regular polygon and found it to be true too. In the website it is mentioned that the result holds for any circle with center at the centroid of the triangle, but it does not mention whether the result holds for any other polygon.

I will propose the following generalization:

Consider any regular polygon (n-gon) and a point $P$ on its circumcircle (or on any other circle with center at the centroid of the n-gon). Denote the vertices of the n-gon as $A_i$. Then, it follows

$$K_n=\sum_{1}^{n}{A_iP^2}$$

Where $K_n$ is a constant.

On the other hand, in the case of a triangle, it admits a 3D-generalization(?) as you can see in this link (although they do not mention it in the link)

http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/3DExercise.shtml

I have noticed that this is also true for the insphere of the tetrahedron, so I suspect that for any sphere centred at the centroid the result holds, just as the 2D case. I checking whether the result holds for a cube, but failed. Although it is true just for some segments of the cube since we can inscribed a tetrahedron in a cube.

Does anyone know whether this generalization is indeed new?

Thanks in advance.

EDITED 1: I have removed the golden ratio part for being irrelevant.

EDITED 2: Here is what I think is a more general result:

http://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2016/07/sum-of-squares-of-distances-to-vertices.html

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the complex plane the vertices of a regular polygon of $n$ sides and radius $1$ can be conveniently written as $A_i=e^{i2\pi/n}$. A generic point on the same unit circle is $P=e^{i\theta}$. Then:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\overline{A_iP}^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|P-A_i|^2=
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2-2\,\hbox{Re}\ e^{i\theta-i2\pi/n})=
2n-2e^{i\theta}\,\hbox{Re}\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{-i2\pi/n}=2n.
$$
For a regular polygon with $n$ sides and radius $r_n$ we find then $K_n=2nr_n^2$.

Regular polygons with $n$ sides of unit length have a radius $r_n=(1/2)/\sin(\pi/n)$, so in that case:
$$
K_5=10\cdot{2\over5-\sqrt5}=5+\sqrt5=6+2\phi,
$$
where $\phi=(\sqrt5-1)/2$.

EDIT 1.

An analogous reasoning can be made for $n$ points in $d$-dimensional space. Let $A_1,\dots, A_n$ be the points, $C$ their centroid and $P$ another point at distance $R$ from $C$. Define vectors $\vec{a}_i=A_i-C$ and $\vec{p}=P-C$; by definition of centroid we have then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\vec{a}_i=0$ and:
$$
K_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\overline{A_iP}^2=
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\vec{a}_i-\vec{p})^2=
\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a}_i^2+nR^2+2\vec{p}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}\vec{a}_i=
\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a}_i^2+nR^2,
$$
where ${a}_i^2=\overline{A_iC}^2$.
This result does not change as long as $P$ stays on a sphere of center $C$ and radius $R$. In particular, if $\overline{A_iC}=R$ for every $A_i$, then we recover the result given for a regular polygon: $K_n=2nR^2$.

EDIT 2.

In particular, for a regular polyhedron with $n$ vertices, you have $a_i=r$ (polyhedron radius) for every $i$, so that
$$
K_n=nr^2+nR^2.
$$ 
The "more general result" cited in the question is nothing but this equality for $n=4$ (tetrahedron). The same equality holds if the $n$ points are all at the same distance $r$ from their centroid, even if they don't form a regular polyhedron: that's the case, for instance, of a [semiregular polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiregular_polyhedron).

Comment: thank you very much for the proof. Sorry, I made a mistake, the correct form would be like this:

(K_5/50) - 3 = phi

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: Your definition of $K_n$ depends on the radius (or side) of the polygon. So your statement about $K_5$ does not make sense, unless you specify some other condition (e.g side length = 5).

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot to mention that. Sorry. Side length = 5. Anyway, I realized the relation is not relevant. Thank you again.

Comment: I've just edited my answer to address the more general case.

Comment: Here is a more general result: http://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2016/07/sum-of-squares-of-distances-to-vertices.html

Comment: I have edited it to include the more general case.

Comment: That result is only a particular case of my formula: for a tetrahedron $a_i^2$ is constant (called $R^2$ on that page) while what I called $R$ is their $r$. Having $n=4$ you get $4R^2+4r^2$.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: Ah, I have to admit I did not understand very much your proof since I do not know how to use complex numbers to prove anything (I am not a mathematician). Thank you again, Aretino.

Comment: If you go on reading you'll notice that my second (and more general) proof does not use complex numbers, but only vectors.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know (or have the posibility to find) any reference of this? A friend from Vietnam mentioned Jacobi but he also said he has not reference.

Comment: I don't know, sorry. My proof using vectors is very simple, so I think it is a well known identity, but I have no idea of who stated that for the first time.

Comment: See also here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207096/relation-average-squared-distance-to-all-points-and-squared-distance-to-ce You might ask the author of that question for more details.

Comment: But see here too: https://www.jstor.org/stable/3647907?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: The paper cited above (by Apostol and Mnatsakanian) contains my formulas above and many more. The earliest reference cited therein is a paper by Jacob Steiner (1882), who published them for the planar case only.

Comment: Did Apostol and Mnatsakanian consider this result in the paper you cited? Check this link:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1894473/sum-of-the-square-distances-from-a-point-to-the-sides-faces-of-a-regular-polygon?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes, it is  a particular case of their Theorem 1, summarized then in formula $(3')$. You can download that paper [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.456.305&rep=rep1&type=pdf).