# Visualise proof for relation between average (squared) distance to all points, and (squared) distance to centroid

Tags: geometry, variance, centroid

Consider a set of real numbers $S=\{ a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$ and $\mu$ denotes the mean of all the points. Consider a number $z$, then it is known that -
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (z-a_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i - \mu)^2 + |S|(z-\mu)^2$$

For proof see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207096/relation-average-squared-distance-to-all-points-and-squared-distance-to-ce). However, I am unable to visualise this fact geometrically on a number line. Without the proof, if I look at the above equation, it does not look immediately logical to me. How do I convince myself about this result geometrically?